# I can't run PHP code with HTML

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on my website and it includes php / html / css . i want to save user information and here my html codes ;

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <form class="form-signin" action="" method="post" style="max-width:500px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <h2 class="form-heading">Yeni Musteri Kayit</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-success">

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="adsyd">Ad Soyad</label>
          <input type="text" id="adsyd" name="adsoyad" class="form-control" placeholder="Ad Soyad" required autofocus>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Telefon Numarasi</label>
          <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefon NumarasÄ±" required autofocus>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="surname">Adres</label>
          <input type="text" id="adres" name="adres" class="form-control" placeholder="Adres" required autofocus>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="surname">Kayit Tarihi</label>
          <input type="text" id="kyt" name="kyt" class="form-control" placeholder="KayÄ±t Tarihi" required autofocus>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

         <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Kaydet</button>
    </form>
    </div>
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['adsoyad'])) {

    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '1234', 'esranur');    

    if($db->connect_errno) die ('Bağlantı hatası:' . $db->connect_errno);

    $stmt=$db->prepare("insert into musteri values (NULL,?,?,?,?)");   

    if($stmt === FALSE) die("Sorgu hatası". $db ->error);

    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['adsoyad'],$_POST['telefon'],$_POST['adres']);

    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

I dont have problem with html and css codes but when i try to add php code after last div it doesn't recognize the code, it recognize like text and doesn't run code, just print like text. Am I doing it with wrong place? I working with netbeans. Thank you

Comment: Sounds like your file extension is `.html` instead of `.php`.

Comment: Are you putting the php code inside <?php ?>

Comment: yes im putting like this <?php ?> and writing after last </div>

Comment: what is the extension of your file?

Comment: Rene Korss Thank you but my file extension is already .php

Comment: can you post your PHP please?

Comment: 1) Is your webserver running? 2) Is it running PHP (did you make sure of it)? 3) Is your page stored in the configured `localhost` environment?

Comment: Do you have a web server running? or are you running it from `file://`

Comment: how do you run your php code? do you use any web server?

Comment: This sounds like a server configuration problem. This issue can have multiple sources, for exmaple the file type .php is not mapped to get executed through the PHP engine or there are SELinux settings enabled, that prevent an execution. Or, or, or…

Comment: i working with xampp but this time i forgot  moving the project file to my xampp files, i trying now

Comment: i still have same problem. i moved my project file into xampp/htcdocs. here my path ; file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mine/new.php

Comment: i can not add my php code, stackoverflow recognize part of my code not all, even so i adding with edit

Comment: You need to access `http://localhost` in your browser, and not just run the file.

Comment: ^True that @iknk It wont work unless you run it on localhost, check the answer below `;-)`

Comment: Sorry my bad using stackoverflow.. im new here, and sorry my bad english, Thank you all ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a folder `test` in `C:/xampp/htdocs/`, result : `C:/xampp/htdocs/test`

copy all project to `test` folder.

open a browser and go to this address: `http://localhost/test`

1. You must have an active apache service on your machine(Ex. Windows).
2. apache must be in run mode without error!
3. all `.html` files that have `php` code in it, muse change to `.php`
4. If `http://localhost/test` not work, write your file name end of address(Ex. `http://localhost/test/my_file.php`);

Answer (score 1):

*i still have same problem. i moved my project file into xampp/htcdocs. here my path ; file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mine/new.php and here my php code;*

You are not running your file on localhost and rather `file:///`

Change your url from this:

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mine/new.php
```

to this:

```
http://localhost/mine/new.php
```

Answer (score -1):

Install a apache webserver server for example wamp:
http://www.wampserver.com/en/
Watch some tutorials about it.

Answer (score -1):

Put a info.php file on your server having code

```
    <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

if this code execute and show you server information then your server configuration is ok and your file name is added with some other extention, if not then you need to first setup it.

Comment: i guess i have problem with server things.. i will work on it, thank you all

Comment: who gave me negative point? what is the wrong in my answer?

Comment: because your code will not work, its actually <?php phpinfo();?>

Comment: ha ha ha, you may correct it, but giving negative point is ........ Thanks.

Comment: you should always check your code works ;-)